# For any $m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $p(x)+1$ has $m$ negative roots and $p(x)-1$ has $n$ negative roots .

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-calculus

I want to find a polynomial $p(x)$ passing through origin such that $p(x)+1$ has $m$ negative zeroes  and $p(x)-1$ has $n$ negative zeroes  for arbitrary $m,n$ ??

I observed graphically that it is possible but don't know exact way to solve this .

Comment: Are you counting your zeros with multiplicity?

Comment: Yes. The roots maybe repeat.

Comment: If both $m,n$ odd then graphically no polynomial  I am unable to find.

Comment: The Sturm algorithm counting the number of real zeros in an interval might be helpful.